# Skip compilation of localized resources

Tags: tfs, msbuild, continuous-integration, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In TFS I configured a *gated check-in* for the continuous integration.

Its purpose is only to build and run tests, I want to make as fast as possible.

Looking in logs I noticed that it spends a lot of time compiling localized embedded resources.

Since in CI I don't really care about translations, is there any way to configure the task to skip them and compile only the default one?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't easy. The targets that generate satellite assemblies aren't optional/conditional in the standard build pipeline. The generation of Satellite assemblies is controlled by the `Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.Targets` and defined through the `GenerateSatelliteAssemblies` target.

You could try adding `/p:CreateSatelliteAssembliesDependsOn=;SatelliteDllsProjectOutputGroupDependsOn=` to the msbuild parameters to override the generation targets.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Setting `CreateSatelliteAssembliesDependsOn` seems to do a part of the trick, since now no satellite is compiled. Unfortunately, msbuild still tries to copy the compiled DLLs to output directory, thus failing.

In particular, the step `CopyFilesToOutputDirectory` of the target `CoreResGen` is the one failing.